# How to Replace the WordPress Cron with a Real Cronjob?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have to update some page everyday with ajax call. Everything is working fine but page content are updated when date changes. 
But my problem is I have to make a cron job which is called daily at 12:30 am so I've written a cron job:

--> 30 0 * * * /usr/bin/ruby /Users/tamer/scripts/sftp.rb

But when I start my cron job it isn't working because may be wordpress's core cron job which is in directory wordpress/wp-cron.php is called before server's cron is called.

So, I have to stop that wordpress's cron default job. 
Cron job works fine. I tested it with another code. The problem is 110% in wordpress's default cron job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', 'true');` to your WordPress wp-config.php to disable the cron. Then use your cronjob as you see fit.

Comment: ohk great.. it's working. 
Thanks for the quick reply :)